# How to resolve JVMVRFY107 ; class=com/cmb/gce/aps/utils/MappingHelper, method=convertToDB

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, junit, powermock

I am writing Junit test case for EmployeeSerice using Powermock.
It working on local Eclipse. But it gives java.lang.VerifyError on when it runs in jenkins.

com/cmb/gce/aps/utils/MappingHelper class is used in to be tested class.

> **Both Environment has jdk 1.6, Junit 4 and powermock-mockito-1.4.8-full.jar, mockito-all-1.4.8.jar,
>   javaassist.jar**

Added stack trace.

```
**at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:265)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:202)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:211)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:146)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:609)
    at com.citi.cmb.gce.aps.pojo.IntradayAckUpdaterPMTest.testupdateStatus(IntradayAckUpdaterPMTest.java:91)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:322)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:309)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:112)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:73)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:297)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:222)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:161)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:135)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:133)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:112)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
```

**
If anyone knows please post your answer. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This question needs a lot more detail to be answerable. What does the mocked class look like? Where do your dependency jars come from? What javac are you using on Jenkins?

Comment: If you can reduce this to a [mcve] that would make it a lot easier to debug.

Comment: It's **essential** to put the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: @DanielPryden - All Depedecies jar are configured in Ant script. Some Powermock test cases run as expected with same jar depedency.

Comment: @LittleSanti - Added full stacktrace.

Comment: The stack trace is not particularly helpful here, as what's important is the *reason* for the VerifyError. Please post the full error message, as well as the source code for the `convertToDB` method that's causing the error. Better yet, try to reduce your problem to a [mcve] as previously suggested.